# Finding a PDF for a two variable function $W = X - Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Problem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent r.v.'s each uniformly distrbuted over
$(0,1)$. Let $W = X - Y$. Find the marginal pdf of $W$.

Answer:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(W <= w_0 ) &=& P( X - Y <= w_0 ) = P( X <= w_0 + Y )
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, consider the case where $w_0 < 0$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
P( X <= w_0 + Y ) &=& \int_0^1 \int_0^{y+w_0} dx dy \\
P( X <= w_0 + Y ) &=& \int_0^1 y + w_o dy =
    \frac{y^2}{2} + w_0 y \Big|_{y=0}^{y = 1} \\
P( X <= w_0 + Y ) &=& \frac{1}{2} + w_0 \\
F(w) &=& w + \frac{1}{2} \\
F(x,y) &=& x - y + \frac{1}{2} \\
F_x(x,y) &=& -y \\
F_y(x,y) &=& x \\
\end{eqnarray*}
I know this is not right but where did I go wrong? The book
got:
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_w(w) &=& -w + 1 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Bob

Comment: It should be $\Pr(X \leqslant w_0 + Y) = \int_0^1 \int_{0}^{\max(0, \min(1, y+w_0))} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$

Comment: The formula at the end of the post is not what the book is saying.

Comment: Sasha, for the case of $w_0 < 0$ our answers are the same. However, it does not work out to the right answer. What am I missing? Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F_W(w) = P(X-Y \leq w) = \int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{x=-\infty}^{y+w}f_{XY}(x,y)\text{dxdy}$$

$$
\begin{align}
f_W(w) & = \frac{dF_W(w)}{dw} \\
 &   \\
 & = \int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial{w}}\int_{x=-\infty}^{y+w}f_{XY}(x,y)\text{dx}\right]\text{dy} \\ 
 &   \\ 
 & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{XY}(y+w,y)\text{dy} \\
 &   \\ 
 & =  \:\: \{\text{independence}\} \\
 &   \\
 & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(y+w)f_{Y}(y)\text{dy} \\
 \end{align}
$$